# GET data not being sent with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to add some data to a page using AJAX. I have written the following code for the purpose. The problem is that the call is not returning any data.
The PHP file is just for test purposes as of now. Obviously, some actually functionality will be added to it.
Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addprod(prodid) {
        var xmlHttp;
        if (prodid="") {
            document.getelementbyID("newprod").innerhtml="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlHttp.readystate==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
                document.getelementbyID("newprod").innerhtml=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET","add_row.php?q="+prodid,true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<span id="newprod"></span>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="addprodbyid" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product ID" onkeyup="addprod(this.value)" />
</form>
```

add_row.php:

```
<?php
$prod_id=$_REQUEST['q'];
echo $prod_id;
?>
```

I tried checking with Firebug. The AJAX call is working, but no data is being sent to the PHP file. The URL that gets called everytime is `add_row.php?q=`.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`ing "prodid" before you send it in the request? It's possible that prodid simply isn't assigned a value.

Comment: I tried it now. It IS assigned a value.

Comment: You are sending request to "add_row.php". The file name you are trying to receive the call is "add_prod.php", is that typo?

Comment: Oh,sorry. Indeed, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mistakenly assign inside if condition

```
 if (prodid = "") {
            document.getelementbyID("newprod").innerhtml="";
            return;
        }
```

correct is

```
 if (prodid == "") {
            document.getelementbyID("newprod").innerhtml="";
            return;
        }
```

Comment: @user3736335 check it carefully you write prodid = "" inside if condition and that is wrong. I write prodid == "". look carefully in side if()

Comment: @user3736335 if you still didn't find difference or understand your  fault in code then just copy my code and replace it and see the difference in output

Comment: Nope. I got it. I was assigning it instead of checking. Big mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not with jquery simple

```
function addprod(prodid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "add_row.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {'q':prodid},
            success: function(data){
                $("#newprod").html(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                $("#newprod").html('There is error while submit');
            }
        });
     }
```

add_row.php:

```
$prod_id=$_POST['q'];
echo $prod_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But what is the possible problem in the method I followed. It should work too, right?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
xmlHttp.readystate
```

is not a type, then correct it as (s => S)

```
xmlHttp.readyState
```

Comment: I did this, and got a new error 
`TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function
document.getElementByID("newprod").innerHtml=xmlHttp.responseText;`

Comment: You have another typo. ByID => ById. Now it should work.

Comment: Nope. It merely removes the error. The get request still isn't sending anything.

Comment: It is finally found that your problem was simply typo. Next time you post any question check your typo first since it gives nothing informative to other users.

Answer (score 0):

If you still curious about why your variant may not work: first of all, move your `onreadystatechange` function below `xmlhttp.send()`. Also try to change `onreadystatechange` a little

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","add_row.php?q="+prodid,true);
xmlHttp.send();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState != 4) return
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        document.getelementbyID("newprod").innerhtml=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

It's seems no change from your variant, but that is the one that helped me one day.